# Convert a string to datetime format in asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have a date time string `"12-24-2013 15:19:29"` which is in `"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"`. I want to convert this string to datetime. But the format should not change.ie, it should be the same `"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"` format.

When I used following method,

```
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(date31strin, "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

the format is changed to `"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"`. I have tried some other method also, but still getting this same format.

Comment: A DateTime is just a number, the format for the to string can be set to whatever you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you should be parsing the string to a `DateTime` and then format it to the second format using `ToString()` method.

```
//Convert your string to a DateTime
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(date31strin, 
                        "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


//If you want to change the format
string secondFormat = dt2.ToString("Second format string");
```

**Note:** Date is a Date and it does not have a format. If you need to convert the string to a DateTime, first line of code is enough

Comment: Thanks, but here secondFormat is string. I want it to be datetime format.

Comment: Even if you see Date in a certain format, Date actually does not have a format. Format you are seeing may depend of the culture setting of the computer.

Comment: I need to pass this date to a webservice, and that should be in datetime, not string. Thats why i need it ito be converted to datetime

Comment: If your webservice expecting a `DateTime` type, your code should be okay. `dt2` is a `DateTime` type.

Comment: Yes, dt2 is a DateTime. But in your code, its format is "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss". The webservice is expecting a DateTime type, and it should be in "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss". that is what my problem. Really sorry, in my question its "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss". never mind, I have changed it :) ..

Comment: Is there anything you can do? :)

Comment: I am confused to understand the question now. if your code executes and `dt2` gets the correct date, do not worry about its format.

Comment: Sorry that u confused, let me explain. I have a string "12-24-2013 15:19:29" it should be converted into DateTime type, and the format should be"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss". Did you get my problem?

Comment: Please read my first comment. Once you convert your string to a DateTime type, do not worry about it's format. DateTime type does not have a format, what you are seeing depends on the culture settings of your computer. Same date may show up in a different format in another computer with diff culture settings. `DateTime` gets a specific format when they are converted to strings. If your webservice expecting a `DateTime` type, just pass `dt2` into it.

Answer (score 2):

You are not changing the format.
You are parsing a string into a DateTime object which does not have a format.

When you decide to present the DateTime, you can format it any way you wish.

Comment: Can u please tell me how can I do it? I am still a beginner :)

Comment: Use the ToString method with formatters:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

to parse String to DateTime use method `DateTime.TryParse` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/ch92fbc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then use DateTime formating (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to output to aspx page

Answer (score 0):

//frndzz  if you are using j query and you don't convert date in(MM/dd/yyyy) to //(dd/MM/yyyy)  then this code will help you
// i try it and i get the answer

string sd=txtmydate.Text      //sd=04/27/2015  (MM-dd-yyyy) format
          string [] sdate = sd.Split('-');

```
      string fd = sdate[1];
      fd=string.Concat(sdate[1],"-",sdate[0],"-",sdate[2]);
      DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(fd);

      txtshow.Text = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

        //txtshow will show you date as 27-04-2015  (dd/MM/yyyy) format
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

How to convert string to DateTime:

```
string iDate = "Absent";
aEmployeeAttendence.Intime = DateTime.Parse(iDate);  
//aEmployeeAttendence (object)
//Intime (field)
```